# Get average number of reviews from html code - extract number from div numbers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to extract the average number of reviews of a certain product, from my website. This number will be used for google rich snippets. 
The problem is that the website is not open source, so I only have access to the .tpl files.

The php variable that generates the html code for review stars is: $totalstarshtml.

The generated html code looks like this(for example this rates the porduct as 4 stars - 4 full stars and one empty star:

```
<div class="FullStar"></div>
<div class="FullStar"></div>
<div class="FullStar"></div>
<div class="FullStar"></div>
<div class="EmptyStar"></div>
```

I tried using the "if" condition, but it did not work as intended:

```
{if $totalstarshtml == '<div class="FullStar"></div><div class="FullStar"></div><div class="FullStar"></div><div class="FullStar"></div><div class="EmptyStar"></div>'} 4 {/if}
```

And I tried counting the "FullStar" div class with jquery, but this also did not work as intended(i added the ratingValue class to the rich snippet microdata span):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
           var nb = $('div.FullStar').length;
           $("span.ratingValue").html(nb);
        });
  </script>
```

The microdata html code for rich snippets is:

```
<span itemprop="ratingValue">the average review number here</span>
```

I am still a newbie, and may have tried to bite more than I can chew.

Hope someone can assist me.

Answer (score 2):

if you change tag inside the script to

```
$("span[itemprop = ratingValue]").html(nb);
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/co309e7u/2/

Comment: In the jsfiddle, the result is 5, but it should be 4, because there are only 4 FullStar divs.

Comment: @CristiSilaghi there is 5 if you look closely :) Also can you mark this as the answer please

Comment: Sorry about that, I just noticed. The problem is that it does generate the proper number, but it loads too late, and is not picked up by google, for the rich snippets. Its "a" correct answer, just not "my" correct answer. Thank you.